# Groovy v3.0.7 doesn't support static interface methods

Tags: java, groovy, interface, static-methods

I have created a simple example groovy script under groovy v3.0.7, and Java 11.0.5

```
interface IFace {
    static  String sMethod () {
        return "hello"
    }
}

class Test implements IFace {

}

IFace i = new Test()

println i.sMethod()
```

however the parrot parser won't except this.  If you run this you gives the following error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
ideaGroovyConsole.groovy: 2: The method 'java.lang.String sMethod()' from interface 'IFace' must not be static. Only fields may be static in an interface.
 @ line 2, column 5.
       static  String sMethod () {
       ^

1 error
```

Why doesn't the latest 3.0.7 build support static interface methods.  Have I missed something ?

Comment: You specifically mention 3.0.7. Did this work before? What version did you use that allowed that?

Comment: Java 11 explicitly permits static method definitions in interfaces I believe (as well as default methods).  I had therefore assumed I could use this feature using the groovy v3.0.7 compiler - but it rejects it

Comment: Ah I see. I wouldn't expect these kind of features to automatically also apply to Groovy. Especially since Groovy 3 seems to still support Java 6+.

Comment: Ah hah - that backward compatibility demand is probably what stops it.  Never mind I am taking a different approach to work around it for now

Comment: for static methods a `trait` has always been more apropriate

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a default final method in an interface in groovy. Thereby you can define a method body in an interface and prevent implementing classes to override this method.

However unlike to a static method, you will need an instance to call this method.

```
interface Example {
    default final void myMethodWithBody() {
        // do something
    }
}
```